# ModX Evo: PHP error in document.parser.class.inc.php

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

So my Evo site stopped working the other day - just got a 500 error. I got my host to check the logs and found this:

```
[error] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare insert_metka() (previously declared in 
/home/mysite/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php(790) : eval()'d code:2) 
in /home/mysite/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php(790) : eval()'d code on line 12
```

I have tired commenting out the offending line and removing the entire file to no avail. Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

EDIT: the code at line 790:

```
  eval ($pluginCode);
```

Comment: `Cannot redeclare insert_metka()` says that you are declaring a function twice. You should check on your included files. To be sure to not include more than one time, you can use `include_once` or `requiere_once` instead of `include` and `requiere`

Comment: Can u give the piece of code at line 790 on the file `document.parser.class.inc.php` ?

Comment: @user1073122 added above

Comment: ok, but what containt $pluginCode .?

Comment: @user1073122 Sorry I have no idea. This is all part of the ModX CMS - I have no idea what it actually does

Comment: use `echo '<pre>' . print_r($pluginCode, true) . '</pre>'` to see what this var contain. I think there is inside an inclusion or a declaration of something that is already declared.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bad plugin has broken your site. Disable all your plugins and reinstate them one at a time until it breaks again, then you know which one is the culprit.

Once you've done that, post the plugin code here and we can help you debug it further. You shouldn't ever need to modify the MODX source code.

The problem is likely to be solved by wrapping the `insert_metka()` declaration like this:

```
if(!function_exists('insert_metka')) {
    function insert_metka() {
        // function code
    }
}
```

http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Creating_Snippets#Wrap_functions_inside_.21function_exists_conditional_if_the_resource_is_needed_to_run_more_than_once_on_a_page

Answer (score 0):

That appears like a very simple problem. You are declaring `insert_metka()` two times. Remove it from one of the mentioned files. Once it is declared in saved file and apparently second time you are trying to declare it with the help of `eval()`

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot redeclare insert_metka()` says that you are declaring a function twice (may be with your evals).

You should check on your included files.

To be sure to not include more than one time, you can use `include_once` or `requiere_once` instead of `include` and `requiere`

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to `document.parser.class.inc.php` this line i guess you are using `OOP`.

So what you can do is create `instantiation` class for above `class` and then `overwrite` it.

There are other things too. you might `declaring` same function inside of same `class`.