# ModX: Where is the insert_metka function?

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I have an issue with my ModX Evo site throwing this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare insert_metka() (previously declared in /home/mysite/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php(794) : eval()'d code:2) in /home/mysite/public_html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php(794) : eval()'d code on line 12'
```

I have searched and searched but cannot find where insert_metka() is declared. I even downloaded the entire site and ran a search to no avail. I also tried to updated the version to the latest, also to no avail.

Can anyone please tell me where to find this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a database dump and look for the this line in it. It seems that the fault one of the plugins, try disabling plugins until you find it. See [ModX Evo: PHP error in document.parser.class.inc.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470293/modx-evo-php-error-in-document-parser-class-inc-php) for more advices.

Comment: Yep, you won't find the function in a file search as plugins + snippets are stored in the database. Try not to post duplicate questions ;)

Comment: Thanks! That did it. For anyone whos looking, its in the Quick ManagerManger snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your error-code, the function was declared in a snippet. This is because Modx has this way of caching snippets to speed up the performance. They make static files of your snippets wrapped as a function.

This may cause errors if the same function is called twice and you declared a function within it. I suspect that is what is going on here.

To solve this issue, simply wrap your entire function in `function_exists` like so:

```
if (!function_exists("insert_metka")) {
    function insert_metka() {
        // Stuff goes here
    }
}
```

Sidenote: This is in addition to the answer given by Vasis. You should search your snippets, extras and plugins. It should be located somewhere in those files. It is not a function provided from the Modx core.